# Como realizar conversion de fecha YYYY-mm-dd en bash

Tags: bash, date, shell

Como puedo obtener el formato de una fecha en especifico
tengo la siguiente fecha:

```
18APR01
```

pero ese formato no deseo, 
el codigo que tengo es el siguiente:

```
date --date=18APR01 +%Y-%m-%d
```

Salida:

```
2001-04-18
```

Lo que en realidad quiero es que la salida sea:

```
2018-04-01
```

Como puedo lograr ese resultado?

Comment: Pueba con `DATE="18APR01"; date -d"$DATE" +%Y%m%d`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aunque el comando `date` es [muy flexible](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/General-date-syntax.html#General-date-syntax) en cuanto al formato de lo que admite en `--date`, sin embargo no admite que le especifiques tus propios formatos, y el que tú usas tiene para él otro significado.

En concreto, cuando usas un patrón de tipo `XXYYYZZ` donde `XX`, `ZZ` son números, pero `YYY` son letras, asume que `XX` es el día, `ZZ` el año, e `YYY` la abreviatura del nombre del mes, lo  que no encaja en tu caso.

Si pones sólo `YYYZZ`, entonces asume que `YYY` es el nombre del mes, y `ZZ` el día, dándole al año el valor del año actual. En tu caso esto serviría, al menos en el ejemplo que has puesto, ya que el año (18) coincide con el año actual. Por tanto una opción sería eliminar los dos primeros caracteres de tu cadena. Ejemplo (en un shell script):

```bash
FECHA=18APR01
date --date=${FECHA:2} +%Y-%m-%d
```

Resultado:

```bash
2018-04-01
```

Naturalmente si no todas tus fechas comienzan por 18 este truco no vale. En ese caso no vas a poder usar el comando `date`, pero puedes tirar de otros lenguajes de scripting que tengan una buena biblioteca para manejo de fechas, como python.

Lo siguiente es un ejemplo de un *one-liner* que podrías incluir en un shell script, que usa python (vale, quizás es matar moscas a cañonazos) para hacer la conversión de ese formato de fecha:

```bash
FECHA=15APR01
python -c "from datetime import datetime;print(datetime.strptime(\"$FECHA\", \"%y%b%d\").strftime(\"%Y-%m-%d\"))"
```

Resultado:

```bash
2015-04-01
```

---

Por completar, aunque no creo que te sea útil, si estás en OSX o en BSD el comando `date` es diferente al que viene en Linux (que es GNU date), y sí que admite una opción para especificar el formato de la fecha de entrada. En este caso podrías poner:

```bash
$ LC_ALL=POSIX date -jf %y%b%d +%Y-%m-%d 18APR01
2018-04-01
```

(lo del `LC_ALL` es por si tu *locale* fuera español, en cuyo caso no iba a entender el nombre del mes)

Comment: me sirvio mucho, lo estoy haciendo todo desde Linux gracias.